# Only button onclick works, <a onclick> tag doesn't work in javascript when sending parameter to another page

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

First `<a tag> onclick` --> doesn't work (a tag `onclick`) but second button `onclick` --> works.

Anyone knows what's the problem with `<a>` tag??

```
function content(frm) {
  var url = "noticeContent.jsp";
  var title = "test";
  var status = "toolbar=no,directories=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,menubar=no,width=240, height=200, top=0,left=20"
  window.open("", title,status);
  frm.target = title;
  frm.action = url;
  frm.method = "post";
  frm.submit();
}

<form name="f_name">
  <input type="hidden" name="a" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2">
      <td><a href="javascript:" onclick="content(this.form)"></a></td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="javascript:content(this.form)"></td>
</form>
```

Comment: works fine here. done any basic debugging, like checking the console?

Comment: can you tell mewhat it pops when clicking a tag? iam only getting about:blank, and i get right page when clicking button. its freaking weird

Comment: ah yeah. here it is: `<a>` is just a link, and does NOT have a `.form` attribute, so you're passing an undefined value to the function. the input IS a form element, so it does have a .form attribute to point at the form it's a member of.

Comment: thanks man. have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Add return false to `<a>` tag to avoid `<a>`'s default behavior

```
<td><a href="javascript:" onclick="content(this.form);return false;"></a></td>
```

However I will suggest you to separate out javascript and HTML for readability and not use anchor tag on such cases.

Comment: i tried that before but i doesn't work. only button onclick works..<td><a href="javascript:" onclick="content(this.form)">test</a></td>
         <td><input type="button" onclick="javascript:content(this.form)"></td>